# Add icon on a Golang program using webview/webview_go

Tags: go, embedded-resource, cgo, webview2

I've been trying to add an icon to an executable generated by go build. Internally, this executable uses [webview/webview_go](https://github.com/webview/webview_go).

I've used `windres` to generate the `.syso` file from the following `.rc` file

```
#include <windows.h>
100 ICON "favicon.ico"
```

(comand used to generate:  `C:\mingw64\bin\windres.exe -i .\windress-res\app.rc -O coff -o cmd/app.syso`)

After, I build the executable

```
$env:CC = "C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"; 
$env:CXX = "C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe"; 
go build --ldflags "-linkmode=external -H=windowsgui -s -w"  cmd/app.go
```

The resulting executable has no icon.

Then, I read that I have to add a flag to `--ldflags`: `-linkmode external`, but this generates multiple errors along the lines of `github.com/webview/webview_go(.text): relocation target webview_dispatch not defined`.

From my understanding, I cannot use the internal go linker since the built exe uses CGO.

How can I embed the icon into the executable then ? I've been struggling to find an answer that works.

I'm open to any solution that will get an icon in my file, as long as it's scriptable.

Comment: `webview/webview_go` is not `webview2`, please correct the tag.

Comment: @PoulBak Isn't the tag webview2 about the [Microsoft Edge Webview2 library](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-edge/webview2/?form=MA13LH) ? Because it's what webview/webview_go uses. Shall I remove the tag ?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, then it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaand asking the question on stackoverflow is great because I generally figure out the answer on my own not long after. No exception this time.

By using the `-extldflags` flag of the go linker, I was able to add the icon using the g++ linker.

This gives the following command (in `--ldflags`, which passes the go linker flags from the build command).
(Note the change to single quotes for the `--ldflags` parameter, because we need double quotes inside.)

```
$env:CC = "C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe"; 
$env:CXX = "C:\mingw64\bin\g++.exe"; 
go build --ldflags '-linkmode=external -H=windowsgui -s -w -extldflags "cmd/app.syso"' cmd/app.go
```